# How to make a summary page for my form on Dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dreamweaver

I have a form made in dreamweaver via html, however, I want to make a summary page for my form, I have already connect my submit button to another page where the summary will show up, I just do not know how to summarise the information inputted into the form.

This is my form code

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="BookingAfter.html">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" class="subt">personal</td>
          <td width="36%"><span id="sprytextfield1"><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
          <td width="13%" class="subt">tickets</td>
          <td width="34%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="Text">Title:</span></td>
          <td><p>
            <label> <span class="Text">
              <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
              Mr</span></label>
            <span class="Text">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
                Mrs</label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_2" />
                Miss</label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_3" />
                Ms</label>
              </span><br />
          </p></td>
          <td class="Text">Acts:</td>
          <td><label>
            <select name="acts" id="acts">
              <option>Adele</option>
              <option>Sam Smith</option>
              <option>James Arthur</option>
              <option selected="selected">-</option>
            </select>
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="Text">Suname:</span></td>
          <td><span id="surname2">
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            </label>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
          <td class="Text">Date:</td>
          <td><label>
            <select name="datesss" id="datesss">
              <option>April 21st Thursday</option>
              <option>April 26th Wednesday</option>
              <option>June 7th Tuesday</option>
              <option>June 24th Friday</option>
              <option selected="selected">-</option>
            </select>
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="Text">Forename:</span></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="surname2" id="surname3" /></td>
          <td class="Text">Type of Ticket:</td>
          <td><label>
            <select name="tickets" id="tickets">
              <option>Normal £35</option>
              <option>Advanced £50</option>
              <option>V.I.P £80</option>
              <option>Front Row £150</option>
              <option selected="selected">-</option>
            </select>
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="Text">D.O.B:<br />
          </span><span class="confirm">:*must be over 18</span></td>
          <td><label>
            <select name="Date" id="Date">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
              <option>7</option>
              <option>8</option>
              <option>9</option>
              <option>10</option>
              <option>11</option>
              <option>12</option>
              <option>13</option>
              <option>14</option>
              <option>15</option>
              <option>16</option>
              <option>17</option>
              <option>18</option>
              <option>19</option>
              <option>20</option>
              <option>21</option>
              <option>22</option>
              <option>23</option>
              <option>24</option>
              <option>25</option>
              <option>26</option>
              <option>27</option>
              <option>28</option>
              <option>29</option>
              <option>30</option>
              <option>31</option>
              <option selected="selected">-</option>
            </select>
            <select name="Month" id="Month">
              <option>January</option>
              <option>February</option>
              <option>March</option>
              <option>April</option>
              <option>May</option>
              <option>June</option>
              <option>July</option>
              <option>August</option>
              <option>September</option>
              <option>October</option>
              <option>November</option>
              <option>December</option>
              <option selected="selected">-</option>
            </select>
            <select name="Year" id="Year">
              <option>1998</option>
              <option>1997</option>
              <option>1996</option>
              <option>1995</option>
              <option>1994</option>
              <option>1993</option>
              <option>1992</option>
              <option>1991</option>
              <option>1990</option>
              <option>1989</option>
              <option>1988</option>
              <option>1987</option>
              <option>1986</option>
              <option>1985</option>
              <option>1984</option>
              <option>1983</option>
              <option>1982</option>
              <option>1981</option>
              <option>1980</option>
              <option>1979</option>
              <option>1978</option>
              <option>1977</option>
              <option>1976</option>
              <option>1975</option>
              <option>1974</option>
              <option>1973</option>
              <option>1972</option>
              <option>1971</option>
              <option>1970</option>
              <option>1969</option>
              <option>1968</option>
              <option>1967</option>
              <option>1966</option>
              <option>1965</option>
              <option>1964</option>
              <option>1963</option>
              <option>1962</option>
              <option>1961</option>
              <option>1960</option>
              <option selected="selected">-</option>
            </select>
          </label></td>
          <td class="subt">payment</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Text">E-Mail Address:</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </label>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
          <td class="Text">Card Type:</td>
          <td><label>
            <select name="cardtype" id="cardtype">
              <option>Debit MasterCard</option>
              <option>Visa Debit</option>
              <option>Maestro</option>
              <option>Visa Electro</option>
            </select>
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Text">Confirm E-Mail Address:</td>
          <td><span id="spryconfirm1">
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="emailconfirm" id="emailconfirm" />
            </label>
            <span class="confirmRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="confirmInvalidMsg">The values don't match.</span></span></td>
          <td class="Text">Card Number:</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="cardnumber" id="cardnumber" />
            </label>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg">Minimum number of characters not met.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" class="search"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><p><span class="confirm">*</span><span class="textfieldMaxValueState">By clicking 'I accept the Terms &amp;   Conditions&quot; you are aggreeing to taking all responsibility for all the options   you have chosen and BSFC Live! are not in liability to any changes and refunds.<br />
                </span><span id="sprycheckbox1">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="i accept" id="i accept" />
                    I accept the Terms &amp; Conditions </label>
                  <span class="checkboxRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.</span></span></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
            <br />
          <p>O2 Academy promotes and host performances of our advertised acts each year. We   legally have permission to sell authorized tickets. With purchase of the tickets   we'll have a mutual agreement, therefore accepting the terms and conditions of O2 Academy we therefore are in no liability of any refunds or any changes to the   purchase(s) you have selected.</p></td>
          <td class="Text">Security Code:</td>
          <td><span id="sprypassword1">
            <label>
              <input type="password" name="security" id="security" />
            </label>
            <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="passwordMinCharsMsg">Minimum number of characters not met.</span><span class="passwordMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Text">Expiry Date</td>
          <td><select name="select" id="select">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>26</option>
            <option>27</option>
            <option>28</option>
            <option>29</option>
            <option>30</option>
            <option>31</option>
          </select>
            <label>
              <select name="monthcard" id="monthcard">
                <option>January</option>
                <option>February</option>
                <option>March</option>
                <option>April</option>
                <option>May</option>
                <option>June</option>
                <option>July</option>
                <option>August</option>
                <option>September</option>
                <option>October</option>
                <option>November</option>
                <option>December</option>
              </select>
            </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Text">Cardholder's Name:</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield5">
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="cardname" id="cardname" />
            </label>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="search">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="Text">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="search"><label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
          </label></td>
          <td class="Text">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" class="search"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr> </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need your BookingAfter.html page to be a dynamic page such as BookingAfter.php or BookingAfter.asp.

You can then use that language to retrieve the posted form information and display it on your summary page

Comment: i've made my page into a dynamic page now, however, i dont know how to retrieve the information i have and display it on the page

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: English, if that's the answer?

Comment: which programming language have you used to build the dynamic page, eg. php, asp, net, etc

Comment: Php, is that the best one to use? how will i retrieve the information?

Comment: For each form item (e.g. input/radio/select item) you can use the following:
<?php echo $_POST["form item"]; ?>

So for your title information you can use:
<p><strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo $_POST["RadioGroup1"]; ?></p>

Comment: im so sorry, i still dont understand haha, can you simplify for me??

Answer (score 0):

Change your form tag to:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="BookingAfter.php">
```

Then create a page called BookingAfter.php and add this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo $_POST["RadioGroup1"]; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

That should give you a starter to work from